# Why scanf's errors doesn't let it consume the input buffer?

Tags: c, scanf

As we know if we try to read a value, **whose type does not represent the format's parameter** (eg. `%d` with value *`z`*,...), `scanf` will not clear the input buffer after the reading's error (and usually this can cause infinite loop), but **being a library's function** (so not directly interfaced with kernel operations) should not **use an atomic system call** like the `read` function? If yes, why the output it's not being cleared while with a `read` it is? 
Also when we read something with `scanf` in the **input buffer** it will always remain `'\n'` (new line) character. How it know that may not consume it? \

Comment: 1) `scanf()` is not for reading _lines_.  If code wants to read lines of user input, use `fgets()`.  2) "read something with scanf in the input buffer it will always remain '\n'" --> not always.

Comment: 1) Well I still don't understand why it act like this and also I'm questioning it not about a specific case (like you said with lines), but in general. 2) Can you explain better *why not always*? When the scanf consume the '\n' char? Please be more clear

Comment: `char ch; scanf("%c", &ch);`  consumes the next character of input and stores it in `ch`, even if it is a `'\n'`.

Comment: Perhaps simplify and narrow your 4 questions.

Comment: `scanf will not clear the input buffer after the reading's error` Not matching a format specifier is not a "*reading error*", so there is nothing for scanf to "*clear*". It is up to the code that calls scanf to decide whether to read again with a different format, or ignore the line, or maybe do something entirely else. `in the input buffer it will always remain '\n'` No, not so. That depends on the format string that you pass to scanf.